# Is it ok to put my Linkedin location to the place I would like to work?

Tags: recruitment, linkedin, location

When I lived in South Africa I use to get approached by recruiters who wanted to place me in a job in South Africa. I then moved overseas and now get lots of recruitment offers for the place I currently live.

I have set in my LinkedIn profile that I'm interested in working in South Africa and the various types of positions I am open to but only recruiters for my current location contact me.

I'm not actively looking for a job, but it would be nice to be contacted by recruiters where I want to work. If I didn't change my location to overseas location it could be seen as just out dated data.

Is there an issue with me changing location to where I want to work and explaining to recruiters that I'm not currently living there but will be?

Comment: similar to [this situation](http://weknowmemes.com/2014/04/my-boss-told-me-dress-for-the-job-you-want/) maybe ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to move, don’t use your current location on your LinkedIn profile. Use your desired location instead. And don’t put your address on your resume.

Recruiters Restrict Their LinkedIn Searches by Area
This means when their recruiters go to LinkedIn to look for candidates, they restrict their searches by zip code. Thus, if your profile isn’t coded with one of their local zip codes, they will NEVER find you. And that doesn’t help you get a job before you move, does it?

[This blog helped me a lot](http://www.avidcareerist.com/2014/03/05/location-linkedin-profile/) to understand what your problem is and have a solution for you and states that You should go for stating the location where you want to work instead of your present location.The reason is clearly stated so I think its the best option

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an issue with me changing location to where I want to work and explaining to recruiters that I'm not currently living there but will be?

That will depend on each recruiter and if they decide they like that or not. A recruiter may think you actually live some place and go through interviews, etc., only to find out that you *don't* actually live there. This may be disappointing for some recruiters that did not wanted that to happen, and could be a waste of their times.

Personally I would not do so, as it may be a bit deceiving for my taste, specially if you put a place that you actually are not thinking on living, just with the hopes to get a work there and *then* be relocated.

However, I see no problem doing what you say *if* you actually are going to or had lived there recently. Have in mind that Linkedin is a Social Network (or tool) for you to expose yourself in the professional world. As in any Social Network you are in complete freedom to post the information you want regarding what you wish to obtain from it, just try to do it with care.

Comment: I use to live there just more than a year ago so it could be seen as outdated data by the recruiter. I don't see it as deceiving because I would be upfront about my location. Otherwise the location has no purpose and I would rather remove it than for it to say my current location which I'm not sure is possible.

Comment: @user1898829 I told you what I perceive of this situation. Like I said in the last part, if you think it is ok and actually live/lived there recently I see no potential problems. Saying taht your data is "outdated" is also something you may not wish to portray to potential employers. Enhanced my answer a bit. removing it could also do the trick but not sure how your offers may change if you do that.