# Is it good to indicate I'm looking for a job in a LinkedIn post?

Tags: linkedin, career-switch, relocation

I'm working as Instructional Designer in country A, I changed my location at LinkedIn to country B since I want to relocate and work there. Also not to forget that I aim for a career change.
Is it good practice to create a post about seeking a job in country B?

Something like that:

> I'm doing career change to .... and I'm looking forward relocate and work in country B. I'd be happy to connect with you and discuss with each other.

Is that acceptable? whether if there is a career change or not?

Comment: Well, if your company finds out about your intention to find another job, things might become "funny". But you will not feel like laughing.

Comment: They won't know because they don't have a LinkedIn page and it's a small company where we encourage each other to do what it's in your best interest.

Answer (score 7):

> Is that acceptable?

Depends on your boss and how your company feels about it (if they find out). It's risky, it's not very efficient and there is a better way of doing it.

LinkedIn has an "open to work" feature specifically for this purpose. You can specify desired job title and location and you can at last partially control visibility. A recruiter from your company can still see that but your boss or colleagues can not (unless they have a recruiter class account). Even if your company finds out, it's not a big deal. Many people have "open to work" active: it's "I'm open to suggestions" and less "I'm on my way out".

That feature is also more likely to lead to a contact since the likelihood of someone with a job reading one of your posts is very low. "open to work" candidates will show up in many recruiter searches.

See https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a507508/let-recruiters-know-you-re-open-to-work?lang=en

Comment: I see, "open to work" is a good choice. So it will show to the requiter that I want work there but I'm no there yet?

But FYI, I work in a small company, they won't know anything and they don't have LinkedIn page.
I connected with many HR and other people from country B, so I wanted to create that post to let them know I'm looking for a job.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Hilmar's answer. I did want to address one part of your question:

> I changed my location at LinkedIn to country B since I want to relocate and work there

This may imply to prospective employers that you're already in that country. And to your current employer that you are in that country currently (which may affect your current employment status. Often, you may be required to work within that country or certain states/provinces, etc.)

I would keep it marked to your current location, and just mention to prospective employers that you are willing to relocate.

Comment: I see, I guess this matter will have a lot of debates about it. I did research and read this answer https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/102338/137170  and saw this and I tended to change the location. But I need to rethink again.

Comment: So if I change my location to the moon in LinkedIn does that make me ineligible for a job with NASA to go to the moon, LinkedIn is overrated, it’s not official any company that performs human resource actions based on information LinkedIn is crazy. Saying your in that country might lead to job offers that waste your and the companies time if your not actually in that country or eligible to work in that country.

Answer (score 0):

A post where you showcase a bit of what you do, and how you do it is better. Then, at then end of the post, you can indicate your intent to work elsewhere, and that all parties including those who may have leads on new employment, can contact you.